# `filesystem` with c++17 doesn't work on my mac os x high sierra

Tags: c++, xcode, ide, c++17

I'm following this tutorial:

http://www.bfilipek.com/2017/08/cpp17-details-filesystem.html

to checkout new c++ `filesystem` feature. However I'm unable to compile even minimal example on my machine:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>

namespace fs = std::filesystem;

int main()
{
    std::string path = "/";

    for (auto & p : fs::directory_iterator(path))
        std::cout << p << std::endl;
}
```

I was using XCode, CLion and command line while trying to compile it but nothing works, I have Version 9.3 (9E145) with (seemingly proper) project settings, none of which work:

[image]
[image]

Here is my `CMakeLists.txt` file for CLion:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)

project(FileSystem2)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

add_executable(FileSystem2 main.cpp)
```

Here is an output from `> gxx --version`:

[image]

Nevertheless this is what I get as an output from my IDEs:

[image]
[image]
[image]

What am I doing wrong, it looks to me that my compiler should support c++17?

---

**Edit**

As per Owen Morgan's answer I've installed clang (actual install command was `brew install llvm`) but it now complains about absence of `string.h`. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 18):

The compiler shipped with Xcode supports C++17 *language* features but not C++17 standard library features. Looking at your screenshot you will see the standard library support goes up to C++11, and Apple has not yet shipped a version of clang that has stdlib support for either C++14 or C++17.

However hope is not lost! You can download the newest version of clang from the brew package manager.

```
brew install clang
```

Then you can compile by setting your cmake compiler flags to be your custom brew version and then running that.

Here is a link how to do that: http://antonmenshov.com/2017/09/09/clang-openmp-setup-in-xcode/

Edit:

After installing `llvm` you will need to link your llvm path into your current shell. I have a shell script that I use at work to get this set up properly. Hope this helps.

```
#!/bin/bash
brew update
brew install --with-toolchain llvm # llvm but with all the headers
xcode-select --install # installs additional headers that you might be mimssing.
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile # exports the custom llvm path into the shell 
sudo ln -s /usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang++ /usr/local/bin/clang++-brew # optional but I like to have a symlink set.
```

Edit 2:

Clang 6.0 doesn't have `<filesystem>` included on macOS yet, however you can get `<experimental/filesystem>`, and link against `-lc++experimental`, and use `std::experimental::filesystem` instead of `std::filesystem`.

Final command line invocation:

`Owen$ /usr/local/Cellar/llvm/6.0.0/bin/clang++ fs.cpp -std=c++1z -L /usr/local/Cellar/llvm/6.0.0/lib/ -lc++experimental`

Edit 3:

Current clang version 7.0.1 supports either `<filesystem>` or `<experimental/filesystem>`. In any case, the compiler command line must be slightly different:

```
Owen$ /usr/local/Cellar/llvm/7.0.1/bin/clang++ main.cpp -std=c++1z -L /usr/local/Cellar/llvm/7.0.1/lib/ -lc++fs
```

with `-lc++fs` instead of `-lc++experimental`. 
Optionally, you can replace`-std=c++1z` with `-std=c++17` as well.

Comment: that doesnt work. `No available formula with the name "clang"` it's llvm.

Answer (score 12):

If you don't want to change compiler to use std::filesystem (because it's a pain), another option is to use the [Boost Filesystem](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm) library. Boost Filesystem was the basis for std::filesystem, so for most uses it's completely compatible with std::filesystem.

Setting up Boost is pretty easy if you're using CMake. Just `brew install boost` then in your CMakeLists.txt do something like:

```
# Boost
set(boost_min_ver 1.50.0)
set(boost_libs system filesystem)
find_package(Boost ${boost_min_ver})

if(Boost_FOUND)
    find_package(Boost ${boost_min_ver} COMPONENTS ${boost_libs})
endif()

target_link_libraries(your_target ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```

The extra verbosity in finding Boost helps, I find, to suppress some warnings CMake would otherwise throw at you.

Then in your C++ code:

```
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
namespace fs = boost::filesystem;
```

If you're feeling very fancy, you can use the `__has_include` define to check if the standard filesystem include is available, and if so, set `namespace fs = std::filesystem` and fallback to Boost only if the std version isn't available.

Answer (score 12):

As std::filesystem support on macOS with the official compiler and Xcode 11.1 is now limited to Catalina/10.15 deployment targets and up, I want to humbly add [ghc::filesystem](https://github.com/gulrak/filesystem) by myself as an additional option. It was written because I wanted to use std::filesystem on macOS, so it might be worth a try.

It is a header-only feature complete implementation of std::filesystem for macOS, Linux and Windows, works from C++11 to C++17, and it tries to stay close to the standard. It might be a less heavy dependency than boost (if you don't use that already). In the simplest form, just drop the main header file next to your source, include filesystem.hpp, eventually add

```
namespace fs = ghc::filesystem;
```

and use it like it is std::filesystem. It is also possible to separate parts of the implementation into a cpp by using the additional header files, the readme explains how to do that.

**Note:** It was implemented with utf8-everywhere in mind, but has an option to enable std::wstring interfaces on Windows as specified by the standard. The std::string_view related functions are limited to C++17, as it doesn't include a backport of std::string_view.
More details can be found in the readme under [differences in api](https://github.com/gulrak/filesystem#differences-in-api).