# Trying to use boost::filesystem by adding Boost libraries in CMakeLists.txt but does not work

Tags: c++, boost, cmake

I wanted to use `boost::filesystem` for my C++ code so I decided to add boost libraries into my `CMakeLists.txt` but I keep getting this message and it's not working right.

```
ipo: warning #11012: unable to find @loader_path/libboost_system-mt.dylib
```

Here is my `CMakeLists.txt` file.

```
cmake_minimum_required ( VERSION 3.10 )

set ( CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER icpc )
set ( CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17 )
set ( CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-fast -qopenmp -Wall" )

project( FLattice CXX )



# Add include files (-I option)
include_directories ( ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include )
include_directories ( /opt/fftw/include )

# Specify the Library directory (-L option)
link_directories ( /opt/fftw/lib )

# Add executing files
file ( GLOB lib_codes ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/*.cpp )
add_executable ( ${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp ${lib_codes} )

# Boost
set(boost_min_ver  1.69.0)
set(boost_libs system filesystem)
find_package(Boost ${boost_min_ver})

if(Boost_FOUND)
    find_package(Boost ${boost_min_ver} COMPONENTS ${boost_libs})
  include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
endif()



# Link external libraries
target_link_libraries ( ${PROJECT_NAME} fftw3 )


# Link project "library" when compile FLattice
# target_link_libraries ( FLattice library_code )

# Add sub-directory
# add_subdirectory ( lib )
```

I installed Boost by `brew install boost` and I simply just added the #Boost part to my original `CMakeLists.txt` file. 
What am I doing wrong? Any thoughts?

**update** Seems like the program **is** working fine (I thought it wasn't working, but it was). However, I still get the same warning message.
 `ipo: warning #11012: unable to find @loader_path/libboost_system-mt.dylib`
I started to think that this warning is an Intel issue and not a boost issue as in https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-c-compiler/topic/518493.

Comment: You should consider using `std::experimental::filesystem` that you can access in C++17 (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/fs). Then you won't have to deal with Boost library linkage.

Comment: If you have C++17, then `<filesystem>` should probably be your choice.

Comment: The warning has nothing common with `filesystem` Boost library: it is about file `libboost_system-mt.dylib` which corresponds to `system` Boost library. Do you have this file in your Boost installation?

Comment: Actually, it seems that neither `<filesystem>` nor `<experimental/filesystem>` work for me.
I was looking at 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49577343/filesystem-with-c17-doesnt-work-on-my-mac-os-x-high-sierra
and it seems like I have the same problem as him, that is, the compiler shipped with Xcode supports C++17 language features but not C++17 standard library features. The standard library support goes up to C++11. The most upvoted answer seemed difficult to do, and seems like it hasn't solved his question, so I decided to do the seemingly simpler answer, using Boost Filesystem.

Comment: `@Tsyvarev`
 Apparently, the libboost_system-mt.dylib file is included in /usr/local/lib/ and /usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.69.0_2/lib/

Comment: **update**
Sorry guys, I forgot about the fact that I was using Intel C++ Compiler and seems like the intel icpc 2019 compiler doesn't yet support `C++17 filesystem`.
https://www.scivision.dev/cmake-cpp-17-filesystem/

Comment: **update** Seems like the program **is** working fine. However, I still get the same message.
`ipo: warning #11012: unable to find @loader_path/libboost_system-mt.dylib`
I started to think that this warning is an Intel issue and not a boost issue. As in https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-c-compiler/topic/518493

Comment: Maybe you can try disabling the `-ipo` flag in icc. You seem to be using it, maybe you can start from there.

Comment: @andreee  You mean delete the `-qopenmp` in `set ( CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-fast -qopenmp -Wall" )`? I did it but the error message still appears. I also tried updating my Intel C++ Compiler but that didn't fix the problem either.

Comment: This was just a shot in the dark. Unfortunately I don't have icc at hand, so I am unable to try it.  Sorry I can't help.

Comment: @andreee That's ok. Thanks for trying to help me out. ;)