# Does use of C++17 std::filesystem REQUIRE MacOS 10.15? (Xcode 11.1)

Tags: xcode, c++17, macos-mojave, macos-catalina, std-filesystem

Using Xcode 11.1, building on MacOS 10.14.6 (Mojave), the following lines:

```
#include <filesystem>
typedef std::filesystem::path my_path;
```

...generate this compiler error:

```
'path' is unavailable: introduced in macOS 10.15
```

Does this mean I can't build for earlier versions of MacOS (10.13, 10.14) FROM 10.14, or that I can't generate an executable from 10.15 that can target/run on versions of MacOS that are EARLIER than 10.15?

Comment: It would seem you’ll have to use Boost or separate compiler with extra libraries to be able to run on earlier versions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49577343/filesystem-with-c17-doesnt-work-on-my-mac-os-x-high-sierra

Comment: I already have my code compiling with Boost.Filesystem, but I was looking forward to using the Xcode C++17 std::filesystem implementation to eliminate #ifdefs.

Comment: Not all projects can hot-swap to boost:filesystem either. I found missing symbols when compiling bedrock-viz (a minecraft game map viewer)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means that (using Apple's tools/libraries), you cannot use `std::filesystem` in a project targeting a version of Mac OS before 10.15.

If you have a new enough Xcode, etc. you should be able to build a project on 10.14 (say) that targets 10.15 and uses `filesystem` types and calls.  But it won't run on 10.14.

Comment: UGG -- seems odd to me that a feature of the standard library would be tied to a specific version of MacOS.  I wonder: is that a first, or are there other C++14 or C++17 features that are restricted to specific versions of MacOS?

Comment: And (since you're the resident expert on the Boost Release -- THANK YOU!) am I reading correctly in the release notes that Boost 1.71.0 hasn't been tested on the version of Clang that comes with Xcode 11.1?

Comment: The filesystem bits involve changing the `libc++.dylib` instead of being header only. Another example of this is `std::to_chars` and `from_chars`

Comment: FYI -- Your awesome FAQ on building Boost on unix systems could be enhanced by adding one tiny note, that in order to run the "./b2 install" step, your --prefix path MUST NOT have any spaces in it.  Even if it is quoted, or uses '\' before path spaces -- it will fail with errors.

Comment: @SMGreenfield std::visit is limited to 10.14 and above if you have exceptions turned on.